# Make QListWidget return to first item clicking down

Tags: qt, qlistwidget

I have a GUI in Qt with a QListWidget showing different choices.

When I click down key, lower option becomes the selected one, but if I have selected the last one in the list, clicking down key does nothing.

I want that clicking down when I am in the last option makes it go to the first option again.

Do I have to implement a logic for this or is there any option in QListWidget that makes it behave like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do that yourself. I see three options:

1. Derive from `QListWidget` and override [QAbstractItemView::moveCursor](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qabstractitemview.html#moveCursor).
2. Derive from `QListWidget` and override [QAbstractItemView::keyPressEvent](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.9/qabstractitemview.html#keyPressEvent).
3. Install an event filter on your list view and handle the `KeyPress` event.